# How big database can wordpress can handle

Tags: database, wordpress

press i have to develop a site that will mainly deal in displaying data from databse ,searching data among millions of fields .

So i want to know can Word-press easily handle such case ?

What could be the issues i could face with word-press.

Does Using wpdb compared to normal query make performance issue ?

Comment: It really depends on how you search data. If you search on indexed fields - it would be ok. If you fetch not all data but also paginate them - its also good.

Comment: "...among millions of fields" -- Millions of **fields**? Performance won't be your biggest problem if you really have millions of fields.

Comment: Search for HyperDB at wordpress.org forum, [wp-hackers] mailing list and [wordpress.se]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets say your WordPress website which have 1 million posts. This going to take up a lot of memory and CPU usage especially if you get a lot of traffic.
So your server should handle that.
You can use a good caching plugin to reduce server load.
You can cache the database to make your search faster.

`WP_Query` use `wpdb` class to query the database. WP_Query useful to deal with native WordPress tables. And `wpdb` is helpful when you need to access data in your own tables.